A right timing & route to learn coding as a job searcher
I am not sure if this question is appropriate for this platform. I will delete it if not.
My education has been mostly on abstract math & theoretical physics, and I don't have any experience in programming languages other than Latex.
However, it seems that real-world jobs seem to require knowledge in coding by default. (I am particularly interested in modelling & simulation in a physics lab or finance.)
I am on active search for an entry-level job, and I have great difficulty due to lack of experience in coding.
Of course, there are plenty of courses out there (both on-line and in-person) where I can learn the basics. However, I am concerned that learning "without a specific goal or context" will turn out not to be that useful.
For example, each company or lab must have their own way of using programming languages, and I am not sure if "just learning the basics" is going to make any difference in applying for jobs.
So, I would like to ask for some advice on effectives ways to learn coding "as a job searcher".
Update) Many thanks to all who have given kind and detailed advice!

The skills are more reusable than you seem to think they are, whatever they are applied to. However, they also take a significant investment of time to acquire to any degree of competence, so conditioning your job search on this may be a bad idea. Find a job to keep bread on the table, then acquire the skills and see if you can find a better job.

Thank you. I may have to find a job in a slightly different sector..

The great thing about programming is you can learn it without spending money to take a course. It’s sort of like learning to play a musical instrument.

Think of a fun small project, go do that. IMo the very best way to start

A significant amount of scientific computing is being done. Having programming chops in these roles along with science knowledge is great.

Check out the Coursera courses on scientific computing. IBM have several courses you may find interesting.

The answer has a considerable "depends" component, as it will depend on the kind of job you are looking for.
Are you looking for software-dev jobs? You looking for jobs that relate to your physics/math background?
Each route will "require" or use different tools and languages for their programming needs (i.e.: soft-dev may require more things like javascript, node, html; languages like Python and C have several simulation and physics tools).
If you've never coded, as you mention in your post (sorry LaTex), start from square one, then worry about "job searcher coding". Perhaps take some online courses, get a diploma/certificate, or perhaps try doing simulations on physics or math topics. Again, it will depend on the path and kind of job you would like to get.

I am most interested in modelling & simulation of a physical system (say, condensed matter). My understanding is that similar aptitudes are required in financial modelling of insurance, investment techniques and so on.

OK, I will start with online courses and try to dig deeper.

@Keith its a start yes, so keep your options and mind open while you narrow down the scope of what you want. Lets see what other users have to suggest as well


So, I would like to ask for some advice on effectives ways to learn coding "as a job searcher".

Learning the basic syntax of computer languages such as C#, Java, Java Script, Python, etc... are relatively easy. You can learn that on your free time. You won't have any difficulties at all.
However, most companies don't ask for the basic syntax of computer languages in the job interviews. Often, they will give you coding problems to do during the job interviews. These coding problems are about data structures and algorithms.
One of the popular websites that has lots of these data structure and algorithm coding problems is Leetcode.
For examples, here is 1 coding problem (Leetcode style) :
(1) Best Time to Buy and Sell Stock III
https://leetcode.com/problems/best-time-to-buy-and-sell-stock-iii/description/

Here is the link to a full list of Leetcode problems :
https://leetcode.com/problemset/?page=3
(When you open this link, please scroll down to the bottom of the page to see the list).


I am particularly interested in modelling & simulation in a physics lab or finance.

Find and ask people in the industry you're targeting. So the first thing to do is decide which industry you want to be in instead of a vague 'physics lab or finance'. Then just ask people.
The finance people I know just seem to do things in excel or more rarely python. They're not coders, they're finance people. At entry level they don't even do that much, they just work on what other people have set up for them to work on.

I am surprised by the word "more rarely". Most entry-level positions I looked on LinkedIn already require coding skills. I would agree that they use mostly what others already have made..

@Keith I've never looked at LinkedIn jobs, just speaking from what I have seen in real life.
